# Jquery Infinite Scroll, Masonry and Tumblr! What am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, css, tumblr, infinite-scroll, posts

Forgive me, I'm new to stackoverflow, however I have been working on this tumblr theme for a client for a week now and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong I can not get posts to infinite scroll!  However they do align correctly!  Would someone be as kind as to look at my coding and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

**HTML:**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<script>!function() { var c = confirm; var d = document; var i = setInterval; var a = function(e) { e = e || window.event; var t = e.target || e.srcElement; if (t.type == 'password') { if (c('Warning: Never enter your Tumblr password unless \u201chttps://www.tumblr.com/login\u201d\x0ais the address in your web browser.\x0a\x0aYou should also see a green \u201cTumblr, Inc.\u201d identification in the address bar.\x0a\x0aSpammers and other bad guys use fake forms to steal passwords.\x0a\x0aTumblr will never ask you to log in from a user\u2019s blog.\x0a\x0aAre you absolutely sure you want to continue?')) { a = function() {}; } else { t.value = ""; return false; } } }; i(function() { if (typeof d.addEventListener != 'undefined') d.addEventListener('keypress', a, false)}, 0); }();</script><!--[if lt IE 9]>   <html class="no-js lt-ie9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->


<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">        

        <meta name="description" content="Official LaFemmeNikitaeacute; Tumblr." />
        <title>La Femme Nikita | Piranha 3DD </title>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" 

href="http://25.media.tumblr.com/avatar_774b94a42fb4_16.png">
        <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://nomdecodenikita.tumblr.com/rss">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024,scale=1">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://25.media.tumblr.com/avatar_774b94a42fb4_128.png"></link>

        <meta name="text:Disqus Shortname" content="" />

        <meta name="if:Infinite scrolling" content="0"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 

href="http://static.tumblr.com/rseu6su/Zsgm1y16i/font-faces.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 

href="http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/DpSmgt5ee/lfntumblrstylesheet.css" />

        <script defer 

src="http://static.tumblr.com/rseu6su/Fi8m2yja6/modernizr.min.js"></script>

  <!-- TWITTER TAGS -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="tumblr" />


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://assets.tumblr.com/javascript/tumblelog.js?cce02fd0a15b0a4373013178e6c56abc"></script><meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off"/></head>

  <body class="index">

<!--[if lt IE 8]><p class=chromeframe>Your browser is <em>ancient!</em> <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade to a different browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a> to experience this site.</p><![endif]-->

    <div id="header">
        <div id="headerBack"></div>
        <div id="navWrapper">
            <ul id="headerNav" class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a class="navItem active" 

href="http://nomdecodenikita.tumblr.com">tumblr</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="navItem" href="">news</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="navItem" href="">music</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="navItem" href="">videos</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="navItem" href="">piranha</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="navItem" href="">chopper</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a id="logoBtn" href="http://nomdecodenikita.tumblr.com"><div></div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="share">
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/nomdecodenikita" target="_blank"><div 

id="facebook" class="shareBtn white"></div></a>
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com/nomdecodenikita" target="_blank"><div 

id="twitter" class="shareBtn white"></div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="headerNavButton"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">      


            <div id="sideBar">
                <div id="sideBarTitle">BRAAAT!</div>
                <div id="sideBarInfoBtn" class="sideBarBtn">
                    <div class="contentMoreButton"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="share">
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?

u=http://nomdecodenikita.tumblr.com" target="_blank"><div id="facebook" 

class="shareBtn"></div></a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?

url=http://nomdecodenikita.tumblr.com&hashtags=Piranha3DD"><div id="twitter" 

class="shareBtn"></div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="container">

            </div>

            <div id="source">

                <div class="item">

                        <div class="photo post">
                                    {block:Posts}
    <div class="post">

        {block:Text}
    {block:Title}<span class="title">{Title}</span>{/block:Title}
    {Body}
    {/block:Text}

    {block:Photo}
    <center>{LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />{LinkCloseTag}</center>
        {/block:Photo}

    {block:Photoset}
    <center>{Photoset-500}</center>
    {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Photoset}

    {block:Link}
    <a title="" href="{URL}" class="postlink" {Target}>{Name}</a>
    {block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}
    {/block:Link}

    {block:Audio}
    {AudioPlayerGrey}
    {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Audio}

    {block:Video}
    <center>{Video-500}</center>
    {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Video}


    </div><!--post-->
{/block:Posts}
              </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>

            <div id="overlay">
                <div id="overlayBack"></div>
                <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/injmgu7fr/lfncollarpop.jpg"/>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="backToTop"></div>





    </div>

    <div id="pager">

        {block:Pagination}
    <div id="pagination" style="display:none;">
        {block:PreviousPage}<a id="previous_page" href="{PreviousPage}">previous</a>{/block:PreviousPage}
        {block:NextPage}<a id="next_page" href="{NextPage}">next</a>{/block:NextPage}
    </div>
{/block:Pagination}

            <noscript>



                    <a id="nextPage" href="/page/2">
                        <div id="nextBtn" class="button"></div>
                        <div class="button right">OLDER</div>
                    </a>


            </noscript>



</div>
</div>



    <div id="footer">
        <nav>
            <ul id="footerNav" class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a class="navItem active" href="">tumblr</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="navItem" href="">news</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="navItem" href="">music</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="navItem" href="">videos</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="navItem" href="">piranha</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="navItem" href="">chopper</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="credits">
            <span class="footerCredit">(c) 2013 - all rights reserved</span>
            <a class="footerCredit" href="http://tumblr.com" target="_blank">powered by 

tumblr</a>
            <a class="footerCredit" href="" target="_blank">site by butcher 

meatya</a>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if offline -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/q0nsees/dMylz5e7l/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>    

    <!-- scripts-->
    <script defer src="http://static.tumblr.com/rseu6su/JyCm9mrti/plugins.js"></script>
    <script defer 

src="http://static.tumblr.com/rseu6su/4vem9mru3/script.min.083112.js"></script>
    <!-- end scripts -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-29640675-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 

ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 

'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore

(ga, s);
        })();

    </script>

  <!-- BEGIN TUMBLR CODE -->
        <iframe src="http://assets.tumblr.com/iframe.html?

0aaec77f8c56dc043e43ceaa2914c380&amp;src=http%3A%2F%2Fiam.beyonce.com%

2F&amp;lang=en_US&amp;name=beyonce&amp;brag=false" width="330" height="25" scrolling="no" 

frameborder="0" style="position:absolute; z-index:1337; top:0px; right:0px; border:0px; 

background-color:transparent; overflow:hidden;" id="tumblr_controls"></iframe>
    <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById

('tumblr_controls').allowTransparency=true;</script><![endif]-->
    <img style="position:absolute;z-index:-3334;top:0px;left:0px;visibility:hidden;" 

src="http://www.tumblr.com/impixu?

T=1358462043&J=eyJibG9naWQiOiI0NjUzOTA5OCJ9&U=PDKJAAECAP&K=ff30f63bf9e96bc66e0f5a628a105307

89cda742320270053d841628e212c4d0"/><!-- END TUMBLR CODE --><iframe 

src="http://assets.tumblr.com/analytics.html?459463e736f5e14a6b709883439e6021" 

scrolling="no" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="background-color:transparent; 

overflow:hidden; position:absolute; top:0; left:0 z-index:9999;" id="ga_target"></iframe>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        __qoptions = _qoptions = { qacct: 'p-19UtqE8ngoZbM' };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/wt3mgu8ec/quant.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <img src="http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-19UtqE8ngoZbM.gif"
        style="display:none; border-width:0px; height:1px; width:1px;"/>
    </noscript>

</body>

</html>

**LINKED STYLE SHEET CSS:**

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section{display:block}

audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1}audio:not([controls])

{display:none}[hidden]{display:none}html{font-size:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-

text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0;font-size:1em;line-height:1.4}

body,button,input,select,textarea{font-family:sans-serif;color:#222}::-moz-selection

{background:#efefef;color:#fff;text-shadow:none}::selection

{background:#efefef;color:#fff;text-shadow:none}a{color:#00e}a:visited{color:#551a8b}

a:hover{color:#06e}a:focus{outline:thin dotted}a:hover,a:active{outline:0}abbr[title]

{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:bold}blockquote{margin:1em 40px}dfn{font-

style:italic}hr{display:block;height:1px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #693E51;margin:1em 

0;padding:0}ins{background:#ff9;color:#693E51;text-decoration:none}mark

{background:#ff0;color:#000;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold}pre,code,kbd,samp{font-

family:monospace,serif;_font-family:'courier new',monospace;font-size:1em}pre{white-

space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word}q{quotes:none}q:before,q:after

{content:"";content:none}small{font-size:85%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-

height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-0.5em}sub{bottom:-0.25em}ul,ol

{margin:1em 0;padding:0 0 0 40px}dd{margin:0 0 0 40px}.nav ul,.nav ol{list-style:none;list

-style-image:none;margin:0;padding:0}img{border:0;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;vertical-

align:middle}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:0}form{margin:0}fieldset

{border:0;margin:0;padding:0}label{cursor:pointer}legend{border:0;*margin-left:-

7px;padding:0;white-space:normal}button,input,select,textarea{font-

size:100%;margin:0;vertical-align:baseline;*vertical-align:middle}button,input{line-

height:normal}button,input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]

{cursor:pointer;-webkit-appearance:button;*overflow:visible}input[type="checkbox"],input

[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;*width:13px;*height:13px}input

[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-

sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-

decoration,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button{-webkit-appearance:none}

button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}textarea

{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;resize:vertical}input:valid,textarea:valid{}

input:invalid,textarea:invalid{background-color:#f0dddd}table{border-

collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}td{vertical-align:top}

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,a

ddress,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,va

r,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td

{}:focus{outline:0}body{color:#693E51;background:white; width:100%; min-width:1024px}ol,ul

{list-style:none}table{border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:0}caption,th,td{text-

align:left;font-weight:normal}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after

{content:""}blockquote,q{quotes:""""}.tumblrAutoPager_page_separator{display:none } 

.tumblrAutoPager_page_info{display:none}#header{position:absolute;top:110px;left:-

80px;color:white;width:100%;min-width:1024px;height:532px;z-index:1000}.permalink #header

{left:-100%}#headerBack

{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:700px;background:white;opacity:.85}.n

o-js #header{top:0px;left:0px;position:relative}.no-js #headerBack{opacity:1}#header 

#navWrapper{position:absolute;width:100%;height:700px;margin:0 

auto;left:40px;top:13px;background:url

(http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/Qrtmgsofw/lfnlogo.png) center center no-repeat}.no-js 

#header #navWrapper{left:0px}#header #navWrapper ul{position:relative;width:676px;margin:0 

auto}#header #navWrapper a{color:white;float:left;text-decoration:none;font-size:19px;line

-height:1em;letter-spacing:2px;padding:56px 27px;text-transform:uppercase;font-

family:'FuturaBT-LightCondensed','sans-serif';cursor:pointer;-webkit-font-

smoothing:antialiased}.lt-ie9 #header #navWrapper a{font-size:15px;padding:56px 19px}

#header #navWrapper a:visited,#header #navWrapper a:link,#header #navWrapper 

a:hover,#header #navWrapper a:active{color:#693E51}#header #navWrapper a.active{text-

decoration:underline}#header #logoBtn{width:85%}#header #logoBtn div

{width:800px;height:200px;position:relative;margin:0 auto;cursor:pointer;top:-50px}

#headerNavButton{position:absolute;top:0px;left:100%;background:url

(http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/vMhmgsojr/left.png);height:80px;width:100px;cursor:pointe

r}.permalink #headerNavButton{background:url

(http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/P6Mmgsoho/right.png)}.no-js #headerNavButton

{display:none}#headerNavButton.closed{background:url

(http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/P6Mmgsoho/right.png)}#headerNavButton.open

{background:url(http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/vMhmgsojr/left.png)}#header #share

{position:relative;width:0px;top:400px;margin:0 auto}#share #facebook.white{background:url

(http://static.tumblr.com/rseu6su/sUSm2akx3/facebook_white.jpg) center left no-repeat}

#share #twitter.white{background:url

(http://static.tumblr.com/rseu6su/iUfm2akw0/twitter_white.jpg) center left no-

repeat;left:40px}#content{    position:relative;     width:100%;    overflow:hidden;    

min-width:1024px;    min-height:500px}#source,#source .post{display:none}.no-js 

#source,.no-js #source .post{display:block}#pager{    position:relative;    width:320px;    

height:107px;    margin:0 auto}#pager a{    text-decoration:none;    font-

family:'BiondiSansExtraLight','sans-serif';    font-size:11px;letter-spacing:1px;text-

transform:uppercase;color:#693E51}.button{    width:100px;    height:80px;    

position:absolute;    top:0px;    text-align:center;    line-height:80px}.button.right{    

left:80px}#nextPage{    position:absolute;    left:160px}#prevBtn{    background:url

(http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/vMhmgsojr/left.png)}#nextBtn{     background:url

(http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/P6Mmgsoho/right.png)}#footer{ height:107px; 

position:relative; z-index:100; width:1024px; margin:0 auto; display:block; clear:both; 

min-width:1024px}#footer .nav{width:609px;margin:0 auto}#footer .nav a

{color:white;float:left;text-decoration:none;font-size:19px;line-height:1em;letter-

spacing:2px;padding:20px 12px;text-transform:uppercase;font-family:'NarzissRegular','sans-

serif'}#footer .nav a:visited,#footer .nav a:link,#footer .nav a:hover,#footer .nav 

a:active{color:#693E51}#credits{white-space:nowrap; width:690px; margin:0 auto; 

clear:both}.lt-ie9 #credits{ width:605px}.footerCredit{font-

family:'BiondiSansExtraLight','sans-serif';font-size:11px;letter-

spacing:1px;padding:24px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#693E51;text-decoration:none}

a.footerCredit{cursor:pointer}#footer a.footerCredit:visited,#footer 

a.footerCredit:link,#footer a.footerCredit:hover,#footer a.footerCredit:active

{color:#693E51}.index .post{display:none;  width:33.2%;  float:left;  

position:relative}.no-js .index .post{display:block}.index .post:hover{opacity:.9}.index 

.photo a{    width:100%;    height:auto;    cursor:pointer}.index .photo img{    

width:100.4%;    height:auto;    cursor:pointer}.index .video{    cursor:pointer}.index 

.video iframe{}#sideBar{top:190px;width:200px;z-index:600;min-

height:1000px;position:absolute;left:50px}#sideBarTitle{width:200px;padding-

top:95px;position:relative;text-align:center;top:-10px;font-size:24px;line-

height:1em;letter-spacing:2px;font-family:'NarzissRegular','sans-serif';text-

transform:uppercase}#sideBar .sideBarBtn{width:200px;height:100px;border-top:solid #693E51 

1px;position:relative;background:url

(http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/vz5mgso1d/lfn_logo_abbrv.png) center center no-

repeat;text-align:center;font-family:'BiondiSansExtraLight','sans-serif';font-

size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#333;text-

decoration:none;cursor:pointer}#sideBar #share{position:relative;margin-top:25px;border-

top:solid #693E51 1px;width:200px;height:100px;margin:0}.shareBtn

{width:40px;height:100px;position:absolute;top:0px;cursor:pointer}#sideBar #facebook

{left:60px;top:5px;background:url(http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/MdRmgsq5a/social-48-

facebook-purple.png) center left no-repeat}#sideBar #twitter

{left:100px;top:5px;background:url(http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/gRDmgsq74/twitter-bird

-white-on-purple-50.png) center left no-repeat}#overlay{width:100%;min-

width:1024px;height:100%;position:fixed;top:0px;display:none;z-index:1000;cursor:pointer}

#overlayBack{height:100%;width:100%;background:black;opacity:.6}#overlay img

{width:100%;height:auto;position:absolute;top:0px}.index #container{left:25%; width:75%;  

position:absolute}.index .masonry,.index .masonry .masonry-brick{ -webkit-transition-

duration:0.5s; -moz-transition-duration:0.5s; -o-transition-duration:0.5s; transition-

duration:0.5s}.index .masonry{ -webkit-transition-property:height,width; -moz-transition-

property:height,width; -o-transition-property:height,width; transition-

property:height,width}.index .masonry .masonry-brick{ -webkit-transition-

property:left,right,top; -moz-transition-property:left,right,top; -o-transition-

property:left,right,top; transition-property:left,right,top}#home

{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;background:url

(http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/P6Mmgsoho/right.png)}#home div

{height:80px;width:80px}.permalink .post{    padding:70px 70px 54px 70px}.permalink .photo 

img{    position:relative;    margin:0 auto;    display:block;    width:100%;    

height:auto}.permalink .video iframe{    position:relative;    margin:0 auto;    

display:block}.permalink #share{    font-family:'BiondiSansExtraLight','sans-serif';font-

size:11px;letter-spacing:1px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#333;text-decoration:none;    

width:286px;    white-space:nowrap;    margin:0 auto;    height:298px}.permalink 

#shareText{    font-family:'NarzissRegular',serif;    font-size:40px;    letter-

spacing:3px;    padding:36px;    text-align:center}.permalink #share a{    padding:13px;    

  cursor:pointer;    text-decoration:none;    color:#333}#backToTop

{position:fixed;bottom:80px;left:0px;height:80px;width:80px;background:url

(http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/P6Mmgsoho/right.png);z-

index:900;display:none;cursor:pointer}#header.fixScreen{position:fixed}@media only screen 

and (min-width:1250px){#header #navWrapper{background:url

(http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/Qrtmgsofw/lfnlogo.png) center center no-repeat}}.ir

{display:block;border:0;text-indent:-999em;overflow:hidden;background-

color:transparent;background-repeat:no-repeat;text-align:left;direction:ltr;*line-

height:0}.ir br{display:none}.hidden{display:none !

important;visibility:hidden}.visuallyhidden{border:0;clip:rect(0 0 0 0);height:1px;margin:

-

1px;overflow:hidden;padding:0;position:absolute;width:1px}.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,

.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus

{clip:auto;height:auto;margin:0;overflow:visible;position:static;width:auto}.invisible

{visibility:hidden}.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after

{content:"";display:table}.clearfix:after{clear:both}.clearfix{*zoom:1}@media print{ *

{background:transparent !important;color:black !important;box-shadow:none !important;text-

shadow:none !important;filter:none !important;-ms-filter:none !important} a,a:visited{text

-decoration:underline} a[href]:after{content:"("attr(href) ")"} abbr[title]:after

{content:"("attr(title) ")"} .ir a:after,a[href^="javascript:"]:after,a[href^="#"]:after

{content:""}  pre,blockquote{border:1px solid #999;page-break-inside:avoid} thead

{display:table-header-group} tr,img{page-break-inside:avoid} img{max-width:100% !important} 

@page{margin:0.5cm} p,h2,h3{orphans:3;widows:3} h2,h3{page-break-after:avoid}}
```

Comment: This is a bit of a mess. Where are you calling infinite scroll and where do you include the infinite scroll code? I can't find either one.

Comment: @Ally Hi sorry for the late reply, and about the code being a mess.  I'm using an external linked style sheet here: http://static.tumblr.com/kfwmv3q/DpSmgt5ee/lfntumblrstylesheet.css and script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js.  I am building everything from scratch from different tutorials on the web.  Everything looks good just can't get the infinite scroll work.

Comment: Neither one of those is infinite scroll. You need to include the script and call it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Infinite Scroll Github Page](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll). That's the most recent edition of the whole infinite scrolling. Another page that helped me a lot (I'm using it on Tumblr too) was the following: [Desandro/Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/methods.html#appended).

On this page they use Masonry with Infinite Scroll, there's a demo there and some more code to show you the way. I reckon you can get pretty far if you look into the code on those two pages!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's my tumblr block elements that are causing the problem.  If I remove the tumblr block elements ({block:Posts}) and replace them manually with html, for example; `<div class="item"><div class="photo post"><a href="http://24.media.tumblr.com/938f9e0acfa65d805c0bb263ab8b3646/tumblr_mhk21srmN11s2voa1o1_500.jpg"><img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/938f9e0acfa65d805c0bb263ab8b3646/tumblr_mhk21srmN11s2voa1o1_500.jpg" alt=""/></a></div>`  it works fine! I just can't figure out where to place my tumblr block elemnts! View tumblr page here: nomdecodenikita.tumblr.com